# Azure SignalR Service with multiple ASP.NET Core App Service instances, where is OnConnectedAsync/OnDisconnectedAsync called?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

Lets assume I am using Azure SignalR Service connected to two App Services (ASP.NET CORE) obviously running the same instance of my application.

I have some custom logic that is executed in my Hub `OnConnectedAsync()` and `OnDisconnectedAsync()` event to enable mapping between my identity and some other information I want to store about my User. Whenever I send information to my users I need this datum available to me.

The primary questions I am having some difficulty understanding are:

1. What is the connection lifecycle of a Azure SignalR service when its connected to multiple app instances?
2. Does Azure automatically create an affinity to one of your particular App Service nodes or could the Connected and Disconnected events trigger on different app service instances?
3. There is mention at the [following link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-5.0) that when using Azure SignalR Service 'Sticky Sessions' are not required, which suggests to me that there is no particular affinity to a specific app instance so is the connection lifecycle deterministic in this scenario?

Would appreciate if anyone could provide some insight regarding this as I am not really sure how I could test it properly.